# Injecting a class compiled with a different Java version

Tags: java, spring, inject

My bean gets a class injected which will be used in the (Java 6) owner class. However, the injected class is compiled in Java 7.

I currently get a Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 error, indicating this isn't possible. However, I've been wrong before. Any insight/sources on this subject?

Comment: This is an incompatible bytecode problem, you can't do anything about it...

Comment: @swapnil7 If that was possible, I've done that from the beginning, don't you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do is actually not possible.  If you have no more alternative than using that class, consider one of these two options:

- Is it possible for you to update your java production environment to a more recent version?
- Is it possible for you to decompile your injected java class and build it for java 6?

Comment: Allright, seems like I'll have to override classes instead. I hoped to find a way around using injecting interfaces or something like that.